# 802.11n USB Wireless Lan Card MediaTek driver not working

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, usb, drivers, hardware-failure

I recently bought a Wireless N 150. I inserted the CD to install the drives and ever since then I have had issues with this.

My Laptop Specs

HP ProBook G3
Edition: Windows 10 Enterprise
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz   2.40 GHz
Ram: 8GB

The Antenna

RT2870
802.11n USB Wireless LAN Card
USB\VID_148F&PID_7601
Port_#0001.Hub_#0001
Ralink Technology, Corp.
Driver: 5.1.28.1
Driver Date: 15/7/2016
Driver Provider: MediaTek, Inc.
Digital Signer: Microsoft Windows

The Error
"This device cannot start. (Code 10)"

I am not sure what went wrong... I have tried everything from reinstalling the drivers to installing driverpack to try to correct it but nothing works. The driver files are too big to upload here so here is a google drive link with the files.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gh8R6eZzcYUCvct9n9IPIeCZ8zZD6qL3/view?usp=sharing

Any help is much appreciated :)